# Google ReCAPTCHA - "invalid-input-response" error code

Tags: recaptcha

Can someone please help us understand what causes captcha to throw an invalid-input-response error code? This issue is only happening on Linux machines used by end users from a specific country.

This issue is not happening/encountered for other end users who are accessing the same site/page.